# Which is correct type[] or [type] for arrays?

Tags: typescript, redux-toolkit

So i have the below , i am new to typescript and i am creating a project with react.

But typescript didn't like PayloadAction , so instead i changed it to <UserData[]> and then <[UserData]> But I didn't actually understand what i was doing only that i thought my UserData is returned/sent as an array of data - [UserData] etc....

It accepts both , I am not 100% sure which is actually correct in my case and have tried to refer to the docs but i don't think i have understood how it applies to my data.

pushData seems correct as its only accepting an object containing UserData but not more than 1 entry.

Although this is typeScript it might be worth pointing out this is for state using RTK

```
export type UserData = {
    _id?: string
    name: string
    quantity: string | number
    paid: string | number
    date: string
}

export interface TransactionSlice {
    data: UserData[]
}

const initialState: TransactionSlice = {
    data: [],
}

export const transactionSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'transactionData',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        addData: (state, action: PayloadAction<[UserData]>) => {
            state.data = action.payload
        },
        pushData: (state, action: PayloadAction<UserData>) => {
            state.data.push(action.payload)
        },
    },
})
```

Answer (score 2):

As you said it doesn't accepts more than one object this line itself answers your question.

When defining array with types being inside it creates a type of array with specific length (Tuple).

There are some cases where you might require only specific numbers of elements inside array fir instance when dealing with quadrants and stuff the matrix will only have 2 or at max 3 so here
defining the type as `number[]` doesn't makes sense.
Here `[number, number, number]` will be perfect.